# How to prevent sending login request multiple times from a form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my **login form** I have a method like this:

```
     [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{

var result = await _applicationSignInManager.PasswordSignInAsyncResponse(someParamshereToPass);

// ... 
}
```

Problem is while it is taking time to do the login check, user can double click on the submit button and call this method again and although user has now been authenticated it will try to create another token for him which causes the crash below:

> The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based
>   user than the current user.

I **did** lookup answers for preventing double click on forms, couldn't get them to work and most of them their solution was to disable the button! well then how to enable it if they typed their password wrong!!  and some were `Ajax` that I don't know how to use.

So ideally I am looking for a server-side solution to this, if not, then a `JS` solution. if not then ok an `Ajax` solution!

Comment: disable the button using javascript when the request is on its way. Enable when the response comes as needed ( ex : login failed)

Comment: Additionally (boot + suspenders approach), you could set a flag in your script such as `processing = false`.  When the request has been sent out set it to `true`, and do NOT make AJAX requests when `processing` is `true`.  (Then you could reset to `false` as appropriate, such as login failed)

Comment: @Shyju can you post some code for it please?  I am not aware how to do this. But sounds like a good solution. Thanks.  Especially when you say when request is on its way.. how do I know that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the button after it is clicked.

Only issue is if you use ASP.Net MVC client-side validation, you want to disable it ***only after client-side validation is successful***. ***Otherwise, button will be disabled forever*** if user clicks on the button without entering anything.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account",
   new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl },
   FormMethod.Post, new {  role = "form", autocomplete = "off" }))
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   ...
   <div class="form-group">
     <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Sign In" 
         class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
   </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {    
        $("form").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = function (form) {
            $("#btnSubmit").html("<i class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-pulse\"></i> Signing In...").prop('disabled', true);
            form.submit();
        };
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: how to set it back to enabled? let's say they have typed a wrong user/pass and now they want to retype and submit?

Comment: It will enable it back, because it was full page submit.

Comment: There is no point of using Ajax in login page, because 99% of the time only postback once unless user fat-finger the form.

Comment: oh wow thank you so much, beautifully worked out of the box. Very nice. Thanks again.  Happy Friday :)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button on click with jQuery like this:

```
$('#ButtonToTriggerId').click(function(){ $(this).prop('disabled',true)});
```

But the correct is create a progress bar or a loading gif to "entretain" the user.

If you are using JQuery ajax you can do like this:

```
$('#ButtonToTriggerId').click(function(){
   $(this).prop('disabled',true);
   $.ajax({//call jQuery ajax
       type: 'Post',//Your ActionResult HttpMethod
       url:  '@Url.Action("Login","ControllerName")/?returnUrl='+"%2F",//send the return URl to the ActionResult Mehod
       data: JSON.stringify($('#myForm')),//send the form to the ActionResult  Method
       done: function(){
           $('#ButtonToTriggerId').prop('disabled',false);//enable when the ajax request ends
       }

    })
});
```

Comment: how to set it back to enabled?  let's say they have typed a wrong user/pass and now they want to retype and submit?